# Django url regex termination $ not matching route

Tags: django, regex, django-rest-framework

I have this rule that it is not matching the current route and I don't know why:

`path(r'api/user/connections/worker/<str:identifier>/$', views.connections.Detail.as_view()),`

The current url is: `localhost:8000/api/user/connections/worker/test/` but it gives a 404. Without the dollar sign at the end it works but this would turn it into a catch-all rule for other routes that might share the same path and I'm trying to avoid it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new Django [path()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path) syntax does not use regex as argument

---

just as fun fact  $ is URLencoded so your URL would be available on

localhost:8000/api/user/connections/worker/test/%24

Answer (score 1):

A [**`path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#path) does *not* use a regex. It uses patch converters, like you used in the path with `&hlt;str:…>`. If you use a `$` it is interpreted as if a `$` is necessary at the end of the URL.

You thus write this as:

```
path('api/user/connections/worker/<str:identifier>/', views.connections.Detail.as_view()),
```